# Particle Designer setting background image

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, particles

First of all, I am newbie iPhone developer. I am using Particle created from Particle Designer(.pex file)(71squared). My application is not cocos2d. How to set the background image. My application has a image in background and adding this particle view with particle designes pex file as subview to it. Now, this particle view is hiding the background image with pex file's black background. I tried to put background to pex file when creating it. But it is not including that. I tried to put background image to view that I created to load this pex file, that didn't help. I tried to put background image to particle view that I am loading this view over, that didn't help. Is there any other way I could implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Go here and download the zip to see an example

https://github.com/icanzilb/UIEffectDesignerView